# how to store values from datatable to array and retrive each values from array using for loop in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays

```
 con001.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd001 = new SqlCommand("select distinct TruckRegistration.Id from booking_txn inner join Payments on  booking_txn.booking_ID=Payments.booking_ID inner join truck_log on  booking_txn.booking_ID=truck_log.booking_id inner join TruckRegistration on TruckRegistration.Id=truck_log.truck_id inner join booking_master on booking_master.booking_ID=booking_txn.booking_ID where booking_master.booking_pickupdate between '10-Jul-2016'  and '10-Aug-2016' ", con001);
        DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd001);
        con001.Close();
        ad.Fill(myDataTable);


        List<String> trucklist = new List<String>();

        foreach (DataRow dataRow in myDataTable.Rows)
        {

            trucklist.Add(string.Join(";", dataRow.ItemArray.Select(item => item.ToString())));
        }


*I Have stored values from a datatable to trucklist array*
```

> After this what is to be done is, to store every value in array to seperate string using for loop.

Comment: provide a simple example what do you have and what needs to be achieved. To `List` an `Array`, you can simple call `ToArray`. Current every element of your list is complete `DataRow`, with each column separated by `;`

Comment: In fact you just have 1 column, so `ItemArray` will contain 1 item

Comment: thank you @MrinalKamboj  the values in datatable is like 6,7,8,9 and it may increase .what i need is to  store each of these in integer inside for loop to perform one operation for each values in the datatable ..

Comment: Not clear @Ruben, please provide an example, what you have and what you want. 

You are just fetching one column `Id`, each element in `TruckList`, will still contain one value. Check my example in the answer below

Answer (score 1):

```
 foreach (String currentTruck in truckList)
  {
    // do something with currentTruck
  }
```

or

```
  for (int i = 0; i < truckList.Count; i++)
  {
    String currentTruck = truckList[i];
    // do something with currentTruck
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example is similar to the code below, which will just fill `2,3,4,5` at different indexes of the `stringList`. If beside `Id` one more column is added to the `class A`, then would have some impact of `string.Join`

```
void Main()
{
    List<A> intList = new List<A> { new A { Id = 2}, new A { Id = 3}, new A { Id = 4}, new A { Id = 5}};

    List<string> stringList = new List<string>();

    var propertyArray = intList.First().GetType().GetProperties();

    foreach (var x in intList)
    {

        stringList.Add(string.Join(";",propertyArray.Select(y => y.GetValue(x,null))));
    }

  // Print StringList    
}

public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
}
```

**Edit**

- Convert to `Array`, use following code:

  ```
  var stringArray = stringList.ToArray();
  ```

Comment: Now suggest what you want to do with `stringList`, this is a simple `String list`

Comment: same as the above example, the difference is i have to fill the array stringlist from a datatable. and as sugested by JohnG above is it good to store like  string currenttruck= trucklist[i]; @mrinalKamboj